# Tailwind CSS grid using JIT and arbitrary grid-template-areas style

Tags: css, css-grid, tailwind-css, jit

Based on the documentation, Tailwind `JIT` (Just In Time) mode allows to add [arbitrary styles](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#arbitrary-properties).

I can't make it work for the CSS grid's `grid-template-areas` property. In this simple example, I just want the sider on the left, the main content on the right.

*Note that I have more complex goals, I know I don't need CSS Grid for such a simple layout.*

- JIT mode works as using an arbitrary padding such as `px-[23px]` works.
- The issue lies here: `[grid-template-areas:'sider content']`, as if you go to the CSS tab there is the same property that works if uncommented.

Here's a [playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/RdBJNvL7Y8):

```html
<div class="grid [grid-template-areas:'sider content']">
  <sider class="[grid-area:sider]">SIDER</sider>
  <main class="[grid-area:content]">MAIN</main>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because there are two different classes in `[grid-template-areas:'sider content']`. `[grid-template-areas:'sider` and `content']` because of the space. You must use an underscore to handle the spaces.

```
[grid-template-areas:'sider_content']
```

Output:

```
.\[grid-template-areas\:\'sider_content\'\] {
  grid-template-areas: 'sider content';
}
```

[Reference](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#handling-whitespace)

Comment: Thank you! I completely missed the part about handling white spaces.